# Class or function variable?

Tags: c#, performance

As a means of speeding up my program, I have it look through a list of words and see if a certain string contains any of those words, in which case it can skip following code and move on.  This happens thousands of times.

I'm in the process of cleaning up my code, and where before I had my list defined as a `private string[]`, it makes more sense visually to have it inside my new `ContainsWordsToSkip()` method.  However, unless I'm mistaken, `string[] wordsToSkip` would have to be reallocated in memory with each call and it would be better leave it as a class member.

Is this correct?

Comment: You may want to mention / tag the language you're using.

Comment: It's C#.  I didn't think the language was particularly relevant for this.  I'll tag it anyway, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be a class member. Additionally, if it's not changing between instances, it should be static (all based on the assumption that your code looks like C#)

Comment: Right on.  Thanks! (I hadn't thought about the static part.)